# Access values returned by a reactive function without calling the function more than once

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

My problem is that I want to use the results of a reactive function more than once but this function takes a long time to return its result (a vector).

My code follows the structure below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "sandstone"),
  
  titlePanel("TITLE"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("n", "n"),
      numericInput("m", "m"),
      numericInput("sigma", "sigma"),
      numericInput("S2", "S2"),
      numericInput("alpha", "alpha"),
      numericInput("lambda", "lambda"),
      numericInput("beta", "beta"),
      actionButton("runButton", "Run")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Results and chart", 
                 tableOutput("results"),
                 plotOutput("chart")),
        tabPanel(...)),
        
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  results <- eventReactive(input$runButton, {


  #Code with loops


  #Returns a vector called "data4"
  return(data4)

  })

  output$resultados <- renderTable({
    
    results()
    
  }, rownames = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
  
}
```

So I'm using the fuction results(), and it's returning a vector which is beeing rendered as a table. But now I would like to use some values stored in positions of the vector returned by this function as if I was using a variable... is it possible?

I have tried to assign the function to some variable but it doesn't seem to be possible...

I'm new with shiny, and it's the first time I'm posting something in stackoverflow... so I'm sorry if I don't explain as well you need... please let me know if ou need something more to understand the situation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is define a `reactiveValues` object and assign it the vector of interest only **once** in an observer.  Then use it as you wish. Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "sandstone"),
  
  titlePanel("TITLE"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # numericInput("n", "n"),
      # numericInput("m", "m"),
      # numericInput("sigma", "sigma"),
      # numericInput("S2", "S2"),
      # numericInput("alpha", "alpha"),
      # numericInput("lambda", "lambda"),
      # numericInput("beta", "beta"),
      actionButton("runButton", "Run")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Results and chart", 
                 tableOutput("results"),
                 plotOutput("chart")),
        tabPanel("Other panel")
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$chart <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
  res <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
  
    #Code with loops
    
    #Returns a vector called "data4"
    # return(data4)
    res$ults <- mtcars[,4]
  },once = TRUE)
  
  output$results <- renderTable({
    
    req(res$ults)
    
  }, rownames = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

'I have tried to assign the function to some variable but it doesn't seem to be possible...'
its as simple as

```
output$resultados <- renderTable({
    #assign 
    local_results <- req(results()) 
    #modify
    local_results[1,1] <- NA
    #return
    local_results
  }, rownames = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

req() is used for early return if there no content to results, so that you dont waste time / trigger errors by manipulating a thing that didnt get made.

`<-` assignment can occur in the normal way, and you can do this is in other reactive contexts.

This example shows a modification , I thought it was the most likely to work, as it doesnt depend on knowledge of your columns values, i simply assume if results is a table you can show, then the first row column value could possibly be set to NA, so there you go...